# pointers in sparse matrix in python scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to understand sparse matrix in scipy especially the **csr_matrix format**

Suppose I have following texts

```
 docs = ['hello  world hello', 'goodbye cruel world']
```

I tokenize them and get a list of dictionaries with token occurences and a  dictionary with token_ids.

```
ids_token = {0: 'world', 1: 'hello', 2: 'cruel', 3: 'goodbye'}
token_counts = [{0: 1, 1: 2}, {0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}]
```

**How can I transform the token_counts in  csr_matrix ?**

Here is what I tried so far:

```
data = [item for sublist in token_counts for item in sublist.values()]
print 'data:', data

indices = [item for sublist in token_counts for item in sublist.keys()]
print 'indices:', indices 

indptr  = [0] + [len(item) for item in token_counts]
print 'pointers:', indptr

#now I create the matrix 
sp_matrix = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), dtype=int)
print sp_matrix.toarray()

import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame(sp_matrix.toarray().transpose(), index = ids_token.values())
```

the results is not what expect, which zeros in the last rows.

I suspect that the problem is in the pointer indptr, what am I missing ?

any help appreciated

**updated**
this is what I would like to get

```
       doc0  doc11
cruel   0   1
goodbye 0   1
hello   2   0
world   1   1
```

P.S: the example is taken from the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you gave a sample matrix; what you are trying to produce.

Generally we don't try to specify the `csr` values directly. The `indptr` value in particular is a bit obscure.  The `coo` style of inputs in generally better, `(Data_array, (i_array, j_array))`, where `M[i,j] = data`.  `sparse` automatically converts that to the `csr` format.

`dok` format is also convenient.  There the matrix is stored as a dictionary, with the tuple `(i,j)` is the key.

```
In [151]: data = [item for sublist in token_counts for item in sublist.values()] 
In [152]: rows = [item for sublist in token_counts for item in sublist.keys()]
In [153]: cols = [i for i,sublist in enumerate(token_counts) for item in sublist.keys()]
In [155]: M=sparse.csr_matrix((data,(rows,cols)))
In [156]: M
Out[156]: 
<4x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [157]: M.A
Out[157]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Look at the attributes of `M` to see how you could construct it with the `indptr` format:

```
In [158]: M.data
Out[158]: array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [159]: M.indices
Out[159]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [160]: M.indptr
Out[160]: array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```

The `str` display of a sparse matrix enumerates the nonzero elements (a dok format would look like this internally).

```
In [161]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    2
  (2, 1)    1
  (3, 1)    1
```

Comment: Just saw in wikipedia that one should use another format to build csr. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @user1043144 Thanks for mentioning wikipedia. The [Sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29) page indeed does a clean and thorough job of explaining the complicated way in which `indptr` is used in Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) aka Compressed Row Storage (CRS) aka Yale format. The scipy documentation on this stuff is really disappointing, but I kept assuming they were defining something specific to their implementation.

Comment: Normally we don't manipulate the `indptr` directly.  The `csr` code that uses it for multiplication etc is compiled and not intended for direct use.  Even tasks like row sum or indexing are performed with matrix multiplication.    But there have SO questions about accessing CSR rows directly.  Search on `[scipy] indptr`.